# Creating an SQLite3 database using Windows

Tags: sql, sqlite, shell, terminal, command

So my terminal which says

```
sqlite>
```

and I enter the following text:

```
sqlite> test.db
```

The problem is when I press enter, it just gives me:

```
...>
```

How come it is not creating the  database? I've tried also entering:

```
sqlite> sqlite3 test.db
```

But that didn't work either. What is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

execute `sqlite3 <db_name>` from the command line before you have the sqlite3 terminal open.

for example:

```
C:\> sqlite3 mydb
sqlite> create table table1 (....)
```

There is additional documentation in the [sqlite command line](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) documentation.

Comment: What if I don't have a database created yet? That's why I was trying to make test.db

Comment: the first command will create the database `mydb` for you if it doesn't exist yet.